# Format (make bold or italics) a portion of a Textbox or Formula object in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

I am trying to format (bold or italics) only a portion of a textbox or Formula object (IFieldObject) in Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2008.

I know how to make the entire field bold, but I want only a portion.

For example:

> ...blah blah blah **May 12, 2009** blah blah blah...

Is this possible? I'm thinking there must be some sort of markup, but can't find any reference 
to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by inserting HTML markup in the field (using a formula) and then displaying the new formula as a HTML field.

e.g. 
Here's a basic Syntax formula that takes a field and adds the bold tag around the text before the colon.

```
dim sTmp as string 
dim sLeft as string 
dim sRight as string 
dim sAll as string 

sTmp = {yourtable.yourfield}

sLeft = (split(sTmp,":"))(1)
sRight = (split(sTmp,":"))(2)

sAll = "<b>"+sLeft+":</b>"+sRight
formula = sAll
```

If you place this new formula into the report and then ...

- Right Click the field and choose "Format Field"
- Change Text Interpretation to HTML Text
- Click 'OK'

There are Gotchas here. The original text is not HTML encoded, and I'm sure my example code does a simple one-line thing in about ten lines. Also, if your field has no colons in it, you'll force an error. However, it should give you the right idea.

Comment: This worked great, I added the <b></b> to the formula and then I changed the display (Format Object -> Paragraph -> Text Interpretation) to HTML Text. Thanks I was not aware of this option.

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula for the date part, then embed it into a text box, then you can format any way you like

Comment: This, unfortunately, was not possible as I only wanted the date to be bold not the entire text box. seanyboy's answer worked exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it is doable.

You could create a separate formula field for the value that you want to make bold & insert the formula field between other formula field, which will make it look like single sentence.

Comment: I think the problem with this answer is the dynamic sizing of the bolded field. Is there a way to have it dynamically sized and have the field behind it fit tight? (and perhaps span several lines)