# when text in quotation marks then text should be in bold otherwise regular font in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

when text in quotation marks then text should be in bold otherwise regular font in crystal report font formula

here is my font formula

```
if ({cominvoicedt4.artnm2} = "") then 
  crBold
else
  crRegular
```

please help

Comment: you get data in quotation marks from database?

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this formula as below

> Right click on the field
>    -> select Format Field > select bold formula and just return true false in your formula

```
if ({cominvoicedt4.artnm2} = "") then 
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

please refer this link : http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=11771

[Format (make bold or italics) a portion of a Textbox or Formula object in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987672/format-make-bold-or-italics-a-portion-of-a-textbox-or-formula-object-in-crysta)

Comment: what is style x formula, please can you give screen shot here